# Countdown clock implemented with System.Windows.Forms.Timer skips with multiples of 4

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to simulate a countdown clock on a game, and I have implemented a timer of the type System.Windows.Forms.Timer to do it with the following code.

```
    ...
    private int Clock
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(ClockProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ClockProperty, value);
        }
    }

    DependencyProperty ClockProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Clock", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata());
    ...
    private void StartGame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gameTimer = new Timer
        {
            Interval = 1000,
            Enabled = true
        };
        gameTimer.Tick += ReduceTime;
        gameTimer.Start();
    }

    private void ReduceTime(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clock > 0)
            Clock--;
        else
            gameTimer.Stop();
    }
```

The problem is once I run the code, the timer works as expected by executing the event handler every second, but the clock decreases with multiples of 4. For Instance,

```
If the clock is originally set to 40 and using Clock-- I get
40
36
32
...

If the clock is originally set to 40 and using Clock -= 2 I get
40
32
24
...
```

Let me emphasise that the clock actually changes every second as expected not every 4 seconds.

Clock is not adjusted in any other place in the code. It is only bound to a TextBlock in a window.

Comment: I have the impression that you may have a threading issue. Did you try locking your Clock field so you'll know that only one thread can access your ressource when your ReduceTime event is being raised ?

Comment: Aside from the the possibility of an MT issue already mentioned, what is `Clock` and where in your code is it being used? It could also an issue with the refresh/update of your UI (although i do not think that this would be the most likely cause..) Your question as of now does not contain any information/code related to problem/phenomenon you observed. All we can do here is do random blind guesses...

Comment: Clock is actually a property linked to a DependencyProperty. I will update the question with some more code.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to use System.Windows.Forms.Timer in a WPF application? (If so, don't! Use System.Threading.Timer instead, for example...)

Comment: Could that be my issue? I will change the timer class and have a look. Thanks, @elgonzo.

Comment: A simple explanation is that you call StartGame() more than once before the game completes.  Those old timers don't stop ticking, you don't Dispose() them.  There just isn't much point in creating a new timer object every time, belongs in the constructor.

Comment: The timer choice is probably not directly related to your problem (by the way, instead of System.Threading.Timer you could also use System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer, depending on whatever fits your needs and is easiest for you to use...)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I caused the issue further back.

I rung up the StartGame method to the completed event of a DoubleAnimation which animates 4 buttons here:

```
    private void FadeOutButtons(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation fadeAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = 1,
            To = 0,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        };

        fadeAnimation.Completed += CollapseStartPage;
        if((System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender == cmdSettings)
            fadeAnimation.Completed += ShowSettingsScreen;

        if ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender == cmdStartGame)
        {
            fadeAnimation.Completed += ShowGameScreen;
            fadeAnimation.Completed += StartGame;
        }

        cmdStartGame.BeginAnimation(System.Windows.Controls.Button.OpacityProperty, fadeAnimation);
        cmdSettings.BeginAnimation(System.Windows.Controls.Button.OpacityProperty, fadeAnimation);
        cmdHistory.BeginAnimation(System.Windows.Controls.Button.OpacityProperty, fadeAnimation);
        cmdAbout.BeginAnimation(System.Windows.Controls.Button.OpacityProperty, fadeAnimation);
    }
```

Please excuse my lack of elegance, I am quite new to this.